# Migration issue from ZF2 to ZF3

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework3

I am working on a project to migrate from ZF2 to ZF3. I am facing a problem and try to solve by googled but no luck.

```
$this->dbAdapter = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('db');
$DBQueryObj = new DBQuery($this->dbAdapter, 'tbl_user');  // custom function
```

I need a similar code in ZF3 for this line so that I can pass adapter instance in my custom function.

```
$this->dbAdapter = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('db');
```

Can anyone point me how to achieve this in ZF3?

Thank you

Comment: ServiceLocatorAwareInterface is deprecated as of ZF3 this means the controller plugin manager does not inject servicelocator instance into the created controllers anymore. See this SO answer for a more detailed insights: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36969109/how-can-i-set-up-lazy-loading-with-zf3-no-servicelocator-pattern-from-anywhere

Answer (score 1):

service names are case sensitive

fore example :
zf2 there was "viewhelpermanager" as well as "ViewHelperManager", now in Zf3, only "ViewHelperManager" available.

but in Zf3 add bellow line in Module.php.

```
public function getServiceConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'aliases' => array(
                'viewhelpermanager' =>'ViewHelperManager'
             )
        );
    }
```

If getServiceConfig() exists then add

```
'aliases' => array(
                    'viewhelpermanager' =>'ViewHelperManager'
                 )
```

for more infomation and details, please see [migration guide Zf2 to Zf3](https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-servicemanager/migration/)